# PHANTOMJS LOGIN-FORM evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(Invalid)

Tags: javascript, python, authentication, phantomjs

i want to login to my account but i'm blocked at the 1st step ... i dont know why i get this message here the line concerned

`2017-02-12T01:49:01 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {\n                document.getElementById(\"user_email\").value=\"reelme@gmail.com\";\n                document.getElementById(\"user_password\").value=\"raeye\";\n                document.getElementById('login-form').click();\n            })(); })()"
2017-02-12T01:49:01 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(Invalid)`

Further when the page should be completly load (the script say it finish)  i still get debug verbose saying `[DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r")))` or updating cookies....

the api doc says "evaluateJavaScript evaluates the function defined in the string in the context of the web page" but i don't know what it really means (as i' m total new to JS and HTTP)

my script pastebin.ca/3767160 and debug verbose output pastebin.ca/3767161

any idea?

Comment: 401 is unauthorized meaning you have to login and 422 means your credentials are incorrect. Also why `document.getElementById('login-form').click();` It's a form!

Comment: agree for click() but submit() do the same thing...

Comment: I have an idea, but please post a minimal working script example. Not only steps.

Comment: the script http://pastebin.ca/3767160 and debug verbose output http://pastebin.ca/3767161 ... plus i cant find the proper way to use submit() as you say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target page is a [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), that doesn't have form fields in its code. They are contstructed with javascript after page load. Even on a powerful desktop computer it takes 2-3 seconds the first time.

Therefore in your script you must wait for several seconds before filling in fields. Adapt [waitfor example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to do that.

Also: you use *steps* technique for you script with a timeout of 300ms, but no flag to pause the script execution while the page is loading, better to fix that.

One more thing: to submit the form, I'd do

```
jQuery(".form-view button:first").click()
```

Comment: thanks, could you explain further about the flag to pause the script ?

Comment: ` Formulaire Envoyé Redirigé vers URL: stuart.staffomaticapp.com/locations` WOW jquery()  and waitFor() made it .... great... my next step is to navigate thru the DOM... THANK YOU a lot my brother... but still have QVariant(Invalid) by the way

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can always upvote and accept it :) if you have further issues be sure to open another question.

Comment: i put 10 upvote if i could.... many weeks i was blocked...but i  don't have any reputation to do so